# Read remote yaml ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I want to read a remote *.yaml* file (in my case, file is in 'Public' file in Dropbox) and to parse it so that in the end I have a hash.

When I try something like `open('https://link_to_file/file.yaml')`, I get not File object but a string object, so I cannot just `YAML.load(open('https://link_to_file/file.yaml'))`

The question is: how do I change string object like

```
foo:
    -foo1
    -foo2
```

(which is actually something like `"foo:\r\n\t-foo1\r\n\t-foo2"`)

to a yaml-like hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `YAML.parse` instead:

```
YAML.parse(open('https://link_to_file/file.yaml'))
```

And as [@VoloD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653262/volod) stated:

> after you use `parse`, use `.to_ruby` to retrieve a hash.

Comment: thanks a lot!
for someone who have similar issues: after you use `parse`, use `.to_ruby` to retrieve a hash...